# Tmux shenanigans: Sharing a local session to a remote server for another user to view

Tags: ssh, tmux, remote-access, sockets

I've got an SSH server running on a Raspberry Pi so that my friend and I can peer-program (or really just muck around) on, but frankly, it's too old and underpowered to do anything useful on besides host a few Git repos. Is it possible to use it as a proxy of sorts to share a session running on my own or my friend's desktop?

So far I've been SSHing to the Pi from my desktop, starting a session for my friend to join, and SSHing back to my desktop from the Pi within that session. I've also been starting a session back on my desktop through that maze, so that I can connect to it on another local terminal and use it without any latency, but the whole setup feels really clunky.
Another problem with it is that it requires port forwarding set up on the user side; this isn't an issue for me since the Pi's on the same LAN, but my friend can't open a port on his side so he can't share his own workspace.

I thought I'd be smart and start a local socket on the Pi mounted with SSHFS, so that Tmux would actually be running locally but accessible by my friend, but alas it gave me a "Permission denied"... In hindsight, it probably wouldn't have been too stable anyway.

So in short, is there a way to forward my local Tmux session to a shared device so that another user can access it, without worrying about SSHing back and forth or opening ports?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So in short, is there a way to forward my local Tmux session to a shared device so that another user can access it, without worrying about SSHing back and forth or opening ports?

In short, no; tmux is local-only.

(The [`tmate` fork](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/2523/2168), however, seems to be built for exactly this purpose. It appears to use a cloud hosted service for sharing the connection.)

With standard tmux – instead of using the Pi as proxy, have your friend SSH to your desktop directly, with his *own* user account, and do the same thing as you currently do.

Or, alternatively, directly give his account permissions to connect to your tmux socket file (you'll probably want to use the `-S` option to start tmux with a separate socket for this purpose). Recent tmux versions have additional functionality for multi-user access; the new `server-access` command can be used to grant read-only access instead of full read-write.

> Another problem with it is that it requires port forwarding set up on the user side; this isn't an issue for me since the Pi's on the same LAN, but my friend can't open a port on his side so he can't share his own workspace.

Use a VPN. If you set up OpenVPN or WireGuard on your computer, your friend can connect to your VPN server – without any 'port forwarding' on his side – and then you can connect to his desktop across the active VPN tunnel.

There are several "mesh" or "peer-to-peer" VPNs that make this even simpler, without any "server" setup needed (e.g. Tailscale or ZeroTier are the usual suggestions; both of them figure out peer-to-peer connections automatically).

> I thought I'd be smart and start a local socket on the Pi mounted with SSHFS, so that Tmux would actually be running locally but accessible by my friend, but alas it gave me a "Permission denied"... In hindsight, it probably wouldn't have been too stable anyway.

Named sockets only exist in the filesystem as *names;* the actual socket operations do not go through the filesystem, so they will not be shared via SSHFS or any other network filesystem either. (Some ancient network filesystems such as RFS could do this, but all current ones cannot. There's a reason they are called "*local* sockets".)